# Android - Ant - validate layout xml files for android:text="@string/" pattern

Tags: android, validation, layout, ant

As part of an automated build for android projects, I want to validate the layout xml files contains a string reference (i.e. pointing to `strings.xml`) such as

```
android:text="@string/what_ever_identifier"
```

and not something like

```
android:text="a string not referenced in strings.xml"
```

If the text contains absolute strings, then I want the build process to fail.

I searched for the appropriate ant tasks but could not find any. The closest I saw was ReplaceRegExp. But I do not want the replace functionality of regex. I need something similar to grep.

Any pointers on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are probably looking for is the "-z" flag passed to aapt, which has it require that any strings it knows are displayed to the user come from string resources that can be localized rather than string literals.

Comment: you can also use lint, and check for hardcoded string warning and change it to be an error and not a warning